# create one pdf whilst looping over data in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I came across this taken from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/17-tips-tricks/55-how-to-export-multiple-ggplots-using-a-for-loop/):

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length))
colors <- c("black", "red", "green")
 
for(color in colors){
 
   final.plot <- p + geom_boxplot(color = color)
 
  pdf(paste0(color, ".pdf"))
  print(final.plot)
  dev.off()
}
```

It produces several pdfs. Can one also append several plots, tables, heading to one pdf inside such a loop? I have not found anything useful yet and do not think that knitr, rmarkdown etc. are appropriate for this use case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is really straightforward, just place `pdf`and `dev.off` outside the loop:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length))
colors <- c("black", "red", "green")

pdf("all_figures.pdf")
for(color in colors){
  final.plot <- p + geom_boxplot(color = color)
  print(final.plot)
}

dev.off()
```

Comment: thanks so that easy. I guess headings and tables can be easily dynamically added that way? Would you aggress that rmarkdown + knitr + pandoc would not be appropriate here?

Comment: Yes, headings and tables can also be added. For more complex combinations, I would definitely recommend to use Rmarkdown + knitr + pandoc. RStudio provides a clear and simple workflow and great flexibility.

Comment: Thanks - currently look at package pander, which appears very useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158486/create-sections-through-a-loop-with-knitr/51159788